# Django How to pass signals in Abstract User model for create any custom model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have an Abstract user model. Where I have three type of user and I also have three custom model for three user. I want to pass signals in my Abstract user model for create my custom model. I have an custom model which name is MyAuthors. If I already have any user in my Abstract user model and save him as author but don't have any objects in MyAuthors model then it will create an objects in MyAuthors model for this user. I tried this code but didn't create user objects in MyAuthors model.

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False) 


class MyAuthors(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(UserManagement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
      is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)


@receiver(post_save,sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def user_objetcs(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
       author = MyAuthors.objects.filter(user=instance) #here I am checking does user have or not any profile in MyAuthors model. 
    
       if not author: #if user don't have any objects in MyAuthors model then it will create  
          MyAuthors.objects.create(user=instance,is_blog_author=instance.is_blog_author)
```

Comment: what is the value of `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: @Oluwafemi I am not understanding what do you mean by value of  settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL? please explain about value

Comment: Is `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` value configured to the import path for `UserManagement` model?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule Yes. settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL taking value from UserManagement.